# As long as this is student led

Tags: meaning

I have the text:

> The parking lot was packed when we got to the church. This meeting wasn't just for kids - it was filled with parents too. There were so many people that we had to move into the sanctuary.
>
> "What are they going to do, arrest our kids for praying?" someone said.
>
> "I think we have it worked out," Pastor Andy said. "As long as this is **student led**, there's nothing wrong with it. Mr bookman was afraid lots of parents and people from the church would be there."

Can you explain to me what "student led" is meaning here. All I can gues "student led" is meaning "student led by Mr. Bookman" or something else, but by this moment it has no sense for me.

Comment: this is an adjective, better expressed as **student-led** (with a hyphen)

Answer (score 2):

'student led' means 'led by students', similar to 'man-made', which means 'made by man'.